# i created a randomly generated list and now i have to append an element inputed by the user but the new element to be appended adds infinitely

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist, append

i created a randomly generated list and now i have to append an element inputed by the user but the new element to be appended adds infinitely

numlist = [ ]

```
n = int (input('\n\nEnter number of element(s):'))
ele = int(input('\nEnter element to be added:'))

#generate random numbers
for x in range (n):
    num = randint(1,101)
    numlist.append(num)

#display the numbers generated
for x in range(n + ele):
    numlist.append(ele)

    print ('\nThe Elements are:',numlist[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a for loop that appends the input number `ele` times. By doing the following changes your code will work fine.

```
numlist = []
from random import randint
n = int (input('\n\nEnter number of element(s):'))
ele = int(input('\nEnter element to be added:'))

#generate random numbers
for x in range (n):
    num = randint(1,101)
    numlist.append(num)

#display the numbers generated
numlist.append(ele)
for x in numlist:
    print('\nThe Elements are:', x)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter number of element(s):5

Enter element to be added:8

The Elements are: 87

The Elements are: 77

The Elements are: 53

The Elements are: 40

The Elements are: 58

The Elements are: 8
```

You can ask for clarification in the comment section if you didn't understand the changes I made.

Comment: numlist.append(ele) <-- this line will add the new element at the end
for x in numlist: <-- but this line changed everything (how so?)
    print('\nThe Elements are:', x)
what does the (for x in range) actually mean? 
PS. Thank you so much for responding

Comment: numlist.append(ele) -- this line will modify the list by appending the user inputted value to the list which contained collection of random numbers. The next line that is "for x in numblist" iterates through all elements in the list and the print function prints all these elements.

Comment: For x in range(n) means that the loop will return values from 0 to n - 1..